# Habitat TDS version with Sitecore 8.1.151003

Tags: tds, habitat

Does anybody have any advice on how to get Habitat running with Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release (revision 151003)?  Obviously I'd need to use an older version of Habitat, but having trouble finding which commmit was the last one for that version of Sitecore.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9):

I believe that the version you are looking for is [Commit 1ab932d](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/1ab932df54830f647ec9a1f7affcf4fc68cb8398) of the Hedgehog Development Fork For Sitecore 8.1 Initial (151003)

## Release History of Habitat

I've taken a nose dive into both the Habitat and Hedgehog Fork's GitHub's. Please, if I have incorrectly listed a release or commit, please feel free to edit this answer.

### Research of Hedgehog Development Fork of Habitat for TDS

As far as the TDS Fork of Habitat, it appears the releases are not as clear. [Sean Holmesby](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/418/sean-holmesby) is the primary maintainer of the TDS Fork and may have additional information or packages to assist.

- [Commit 1ab932d](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/1ab932df54830f647ec9a1f7affcf4fc68cb8398) - Jan 29th, 2016 - [Sitecore 8.1 Initial](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/blob/1ab932df54830f647ec9a1f7affcf4fc68cb8398/README.md)
- ??? - ??? - Sitecore 8.1 Update 1
- ??? - ??? - Sitecore 8.1 Update 2
- [Commit aba44ba](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/aba44ba725380c092ad08ac20217e08cf1837b4d) - Sep 22nd, 2016 - Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

  - Confidence on this is low. This commit was when 8.1 Update 3 NuGets were updated.
- [Commit f7d8311](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/f7d83118ac593aa52d0220d099f99e8d7463f678) - Oct. 18th, 2016 - [Sitecore 8.2 Initial](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/blob/f7d83118ac593aa52d0220d099f99e8d7463f678/README.md)
- [Commit 6784c8f](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/6784c8f770c7a3895866cefdc644815b14f34027) - Jan 7th, 2017 - [Sitecore 8.2 Update 1](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/blob/6784c8f770c7a3895866cefdc644815b14f34027/README.md)
- As of Feb 12th, 2017, Habitat TDS has not been updated for Sitecore 8.2 Update 2
- As of Oct 7, 2017, [Habitat TDS](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/tree/TDS-latest) has been updated for Sitecore 8.2 Update 4.

### Research of Habitat's GitHub

For information about Habitat in general, [Thomas Eldblom](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/users/92/eldblom) is the primary Habitat maintainer.

- [Release 1.0.0](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/releases/tag/v1.0.0) - Dec. 18th, 2015 - [Sitecore 8.1 Initial](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started/3d6eaa7946b3471d98d0fdb2cfd255614283ae22)
- [Release v1.0.0.313](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/releases/tag/v1.0.0.313) - Jan 26th, 2016 - [Sitecore 8.1 Update 1](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started/0f0a03b23b85fdea9e8aa6e6dcbecd8564e9e9c4)
- [Release 1.1.0.378](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/releases/tag/v1.1.0.378) - March 1st, 2016 - [Sitecore 8.1 Update 2](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started/a3f31d640491242c7d418ab4182c4b7b60eb310d)

  - (Update 2, was never actually refelcted in the Habitat Wiki)
- [Release 1.2](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/releases/tag/1.2) - July 14th, 2016 - [Sitecore 8.1 Update 3](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started/3704949fddb4875b53171a62f5ec6dd4ad1a1dd3)
- [Commit Oct. 13th](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/8ca0c62b9eebca924c852c85a76ca19dca2db152) - Oct. 13th, 2016 - [Sitecore 8.2 Initial](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started/eb2a7a0870aa7cccbd16d16bf94e577f6094d8c4)
- [Release 1.3](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/releases/tag/1.3) - Dec 29th, 2016 - [Sitecore 8.2 Update 1](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/wiki/01-Getting-Started/487debabac4ee1ec7b2254b2a47786139b13d1f0)
- As of Feb 12th, 2017, Habitat has not been updated for [Sitecore 8.2 Update 2](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/blob/TDS-latest/README.md)
- As of Oct 7, 2017,  Habitat has been updated for [Sitecore 8.2 Update 4](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/Habitat/blob/TDS-latest/README.md)

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful.  

I've tried to run it using commit 1ab932d... there's a whole bunch of missing references (Sitecore.Kernel in various projects, testing project, etc); and all the Sitecore references not coming from Nuget is a bit yucky.

The code is also really old - I think we might opt for creating a new solution and merging in bits and pieces that we need as we develop - hopefully the latest versions (adjusted to work with the older Sitecore version in use by the organisation we're building for).

Thanks anyway for the info Pete.

Comment: @Jeeby yeah never use habitat as an accelerator.

Comment: What Anchio said. Its more of an example POC. Load it up on a current version of Sitecore and then identify how Helix can work for you.

Comment: Great summary Pete. The tags from the original repo are merged across to this repo, but they're for the master branch, not the TDS-latest branch. There's a branch called 'TDS', that is only updated (merged from TDS-latest) when there's a point release (tag created) on the original. It might be easier to find the versions on there. If anyone has other suggestions for how this could be done better, let me know.

Comment: Thanks Sean, the links to the Commit Numbers are for the TDS branch. I made sure of that. The links to the Sitecore version are refenceing the ReadMe.md thag was adjusted to show the new Sitecore version level.

Comment: Yeah I agree not to use Helix as an accelerator... but I do think it's important to have it running in order to understand what it's doing under the covers, and to know what bits can be used in your solution.  That's how we're doing it, jsut with the latest version instead of an older version... so far soo good :)

Comment: Awesome, glad we could help. =)